# Firebase incorrect login swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up a firebase auth in my app. The error I'm running into is that for every time login is tapped with incorrect login credentials, the block that is run when auth is correct is called. So lets say I try to log in incorrectly, 3 times, when I finally log in correctly(on the fourth attempt), my segue is performed 4 times.

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if let email = self.usernameTextField.text {

        if let password = self.passwordTextField.text {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password) { (user, error) in

                FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

                    if user != nil {

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedInSegue", sender: self)
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "loggedIn")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(password, forKey: "password")

                    } else {

                        self.incorrectLoginAnimation(self.passwordTextField)
                        self.incorrectLoginAnimation(self.usernameTextField)


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using the sighInWithEmail function incorrectly? Is there a better way to verify whether or not the correct credentials have been entered?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password) { (user, error) in


    if user != nil {

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedInSegue", sender: self)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "loggedIn")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(password, forKey: "password")

                } else {

                    self.incorrectLoginAnimation(self.passwordTextField)
                    self.incorrectLoginAnimation(self.usernameTextField)


                }
}
```

It's your same code, but I've removed the addAuthStateDidChangeListener. You don't need it there when you sign in.

Comment: No problem. If this helped you please upvote/mark as correct answer :)